# PDO:Individual results from multiple SQL statements executed together

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Suppose I execute the statement

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table1` SET v1 = 'v1' WHERE id = 'aaa';";
$sql .= "UPDATE `table2` SET v1 = 'v1' WHERE id = 'aaa';";
$code = $dbh->exec($sql);
```

Now here is the issue

- table1 has v1 set to **v0**. So the first statement causes a row change. $code is > 0. GOOD
- table1 has v1 already at **v1**.  The first statement causes NO row change. table2 has v1 set to v0 so the second statement causes a row change.

However - the result being returned is still zero (for the first of the two staements).

Question -is there any way to get the result of the individual statements without executing the two statements separately?

Comment: `WHERE = id = 'aaa'`??

Comment: Are you sure about your `where = id = 'aaa'` condition..

Comment: @DroidOS Can you add the table layout with some example rows? I don't get the problem actually.

Comment: @hek2mgl the table layout is not really relevant. The issue is simply this - if you execute multiple SQL statements together the result returned is for the FIRST of those statements. So if the first one causes no changes the result returned is 0 even though subsequent statements may well have caused row changes. If I then rely on that returned result to decide if all went well I reach the wrong conclusions. As I mention in the question - one simple solution would be to execute the two statements separately but that sounds like an inefficient compromise

Comment: @DroidOS I did not so much database programming in the past years but I think to remember that what you say is indeed the case. You need to execute them separately. But what do you expect? It can return just one return value, either the first or the last. If you need a more customized behaviour, you might create a stored procedure and call it. The procedure can return whatever you want and can execute as many queries as you wish.

Comment: @hek2mgl - thanks.  Your comment prompted me to take a fresh look at what the docs say re pdo->exec (I have been using it for eons so why bother reading right?).  You are correct there is no way it can return the results of individual concatenated statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you consider using [mysqli_multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) for your queries.

Comment: perfect!  Just what I was after.